# Understanding Big Query Tables

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am still learning about big query and I have a few questions about how the datasets and tables work. I ran a query and saved the results into a BigQuery Table. Now, is this table a snapshot of the data that I pulled or will the table but updated if new data comes in fitting the original query?

If it is a snapshot. Can anyone offer some help with updating/replacing the data in a BigQuery table programmatically using Nodejs.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table is a *"snapshot"* and will not update automatically. Regarding using Node to programmatically update/replace a table, I'd suggest creating a seperate question for that and try to give as many details as you can. The samples on the [Node GitHub repo](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery) might be enough to get you started however. [For example](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/7c2be88fcc4b5e5c0d0891b68995ede82125efa5/samples/tables.js#L288):

```
function loadCSVFromGCS(datasetId, tableId, projectId) {
  // [START bigquery_load_table_gcs_csv]
  // Imports the Google Cloud client libraries
  const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
  const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

  /**
   * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following lines before running the sample.
   */
  // const projectId = "your-project-id";
  // const datasetId = "my_dataset";
  // const tableId = "my_table";

  /**
   * This sample loads the CSV file at
   * https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-samples-data/bigquery/us-states/us-states.csv
   *
   * TODO(developer): Replace the following lines with the path to your file.
   */
  const bucketName = 'cloud-samples-data';
  const filename = 'bigquery/us-states/us-states.csv';

  // Instantiates clients
  const bigquery = new BigQuery({
    projectId: projectId,
  });

  const storage = new Storage({
    projectId: projectId,
  });

  // Configure the load job. For full list of options, see:
  // https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.load
  const metadata = {
    sourceFormat: 'CSV',
    skipLeadingRows: 1,
    schema: {
      fields: [
        {name: 'name', type: 'STRING'},
        {name: 'post_abbr', type: 'STRING'},
      ],
    },
  };

  // Loads data from a Google Cloud Storage file into the table
  bigquery
    .dataset(datasetId)
    .table(tableId)
    .load(storage.bucket(bucketName).file(filename), metadata)
    .then(results => {
      const job = results[0];

      // load() waits for the job to finish
      console.log(`Job ${job.id} completed.`);

      // Check the job's status for errors
      const errors = job.status.errors;
      if (errors && errors.length > 0) {
        throw errors;
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('ERROR:', err);
    });
  // [END bigquery_load_table_gcs_csv]
}
```

Comment: Sounds good, thanks. I will create another question. I did come across the documentation you provided. It is actually what generated the question. Using this code I was able to export a CSV from a table I created via the GCP UI, but since that table is a "snapshot" if I want to export the CSV on a regular basis I need to updated/replace the table before exporting. But I can not figure out how to do that with node.

Comment: Great. It's important to accept answers when they help you. You can create another question for the automation :)